# Running total of values from a table until it matches value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum, database-cursor

I have 2 tables.

Table 1 is a temp variable table:

```
declare @Temp as table ( proj_num varchar(10), sum_dom decimal(23,8))
```

My temp table is populated with a list of project numbers, and a month end accounting dollar amount.
For example:

```
proj_num |  sum_dom
11522    |  2477.15
11524    | 26474.20
41865    |  9012.10
```

Table 2 is a Project Transactions table.
We're concerned with just the following columns:

- `proj_num`
- `amount`
- `cost_code`
- `tran_date`

Individual values will somemething like this:

```
proj_num | cost_code | amount  | tran_date
11522    | LBR       |  112.10 | 10/1/2018
11522    | LBR       | 1765.90 | 10/2/2018
11522    | MAT       |  599.15 | 10/3/2018
11522    | FRT       |   57.50 | 10/4/2018
```

So for this project, since the grand total of $2477.15 is met on 10/3, example output would be:

```
proj_num | cost_code | amount 
11522    |  LBR      | 1878.00
11522    |  MAT      | 599.15
```

I want to sum the amounts (grouped by cost_code, and ordered by tran_date) under the project transaction table until the total sum of values for that project value matches the value in the sum_dom column of the temp table, at which point I will output that data.

Can you help me figure out how to write the query to do that?
I know I should avoid cursors, but I havent had much luck with my attempts so far.   I cant seem to get it to keep a running total.

Comment: is that possible if there is no match? and why it will sort like that order? what if it is showing from the bottom to the top?

Comment: @LONG Im not sure I understand your question.   There will be matches for all records.  I only included a few examples for the top project number for simplicity.   I'd need the records in the transaction table to be sorted by tran_date asc.

Comment: I was thinking how to avoid counting $57.5 before your get the correct amount

Comment: You seem to have mixed up code and amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running sum is done using `SUM(...) OVER (ORDER BY ...)`. You just need to tell where to stop:

```
SELECT sq.*
FROM projects
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        proj_num,
        cost_code,
        amount,
        SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY proj_num ORDER BY tran_date) AS running_sum
    FROM project_transactions
) AS sq ON projects.proj_num = sq.proj_num
WHERE running_sum <= projects.sum_dom
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6fef91b4b9960e5381a7a7a261402c5a)

Comment: Looks like it didnt work from my primary database (too old SQL server version?), but it did work from a linked server that is a newer version.    Now I just need to figure out how to speed it up, as it's horribly slow (average of 40 seconds / project number).     So I'll look into that.   But, it is a working solution, so thank you very much!

Comment: `SUM() OVER` requires SQL 2008 I believe. You can always add appropriate `WHERE` clause and create indexes to speed things up.